# Time complexity of this function (Similar answers yet one is wrong)

Tags: time-complexity

```
def f(n):
   i = 2
   while i < n : 
       i *= i
```

My solution : So what I did was I looked at the sum of the `i *= i` and I found out that it looks like this :  
`4^(0.5) + 4^(1) + 4^(2) + 4^(3) + ... + 4^(k)` , and the loop stops whenever `4^k >= n` and got that `k=log(n)`, and so the time complexity is `O(log(n))`. 
 
The answer was `O(log(log(n)))`, after a while of thinking I found out that I could have written my sum as `2^(2^k)=4^k` , and got the desired answer. 
 
As I am still new in solving these solutions, and trying my best to understand them deeply so I don't repeat my mistakes, I want to know where is my mistake, aren't these two sums equal? am I missing something? 
 
 I appreciate any explanation. Thanks in advance :).

Comment: 2^2^k is not equal to 4^k; the first one grows *much* faster. Try putting in e.g. k=10 and seeing the results of both.

Comment: @kaya3 Oh wow, seems like I need to strengthen my math skills more, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Also, why are you taking the sum of the powers? No need to do that.

Comment: @MoB. I wanted to find a pattern for the values of (i), so I can try to find how many interations the loop does. Anyway I'm still new to analyzing time complexity and if you can explain to me what a better way would be I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It's a good idea to find a pattern for the values of `i`. But `i` is squared repeatedly, so it's got nothing to do with summation: `(((...(i^2)^2)^2....) = 2^(2^k)`

Comment: @MoB. That clears it, thanks for the help